# python flask TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'int'

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

I am getting this error. I use flask with sqlalchemy and flask login

function:

```
def getCoins(id):
    userr = User.query.get_or_404(id)

    if current_user.adViewStatus == 'done' or current_user.adViewStatus == 'none' or current_user.adViewStatus == 'nope':
        return redirect('/coins')
    elif current_user.adViewStatus == 'watching':
        current_user.points = current_user.points + 25
        current_user.adViewStatus = 'doneBoy'
        db.session.commit()
        return redirect('/youGotTheCoins')
    else:
        return redirect('/')
```

view function:

```
@application.route('/coins/get_more/view_ad/<int:id>', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
@login_required
def getCoins1(id):
    return getCoins(id)
```

db model

```
class User(UserMixin, db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String)
    password = db.Column(db.String)
    email = db.Column(db.String, unique=True)
    connection_type = db.Column(db.String)
    school = db.Column(db.String)
    real_name = db.Column(db.String)
    points = db.Column(db.Integer)
    adViewStatus = db.Column(db.String)
    viewer = db.Column(db.Integer)
```

I need a fast answer!
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, SQL databases usually allow their columns to contain `None` (or, as SQL calls it, null)

If you never set a user's `points` value, it will be set to that column's default value - which will usually be null if you haven't specified another one

If you expect some column to always have some value, you'll probably want to set it to not allow null values. In SQLAlchemy, that can be done using the `nullable` argument to `Column`, like `points = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)`

You might also want to look into setting a default value, like `points = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False, default=0)`